# Other types of .net configuration files

Tags: c#, .net, configuration

OK, so this is not the most useful question since I can't remember the feature in .net that does this. Basically, that's what I'm asking; what feature is this?

A year or so ago, I was working on a project and we used configuration files that mapped directly to a class using the specific attributes on the class members. This is not the standard app.config, but assemblyname.dll.xml instead.

Perhaps it's a feature within the unity framework? Just a stab in the dark.
It is not critical I figure this out today, but it is just weighing on my brain and annoys me that i can't remember!

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the standard XML config, but it is built into .NET. Basically, XML serialization allows you to project an XML document from a hydrated class instance, that will map 1:1 to the class it came from and can be used to re-hydrate a new instance of that class.

This can, in the majority of cases, be done without much effort on your part. All that's usually necessary for XML serialization to work is that the object must have a public default constructor, and that all the state information you want to serialize must be public and read-write. In a few cases, some attributes are necessary to define certain behaviors, like derived classes in arrays of their parent class, and defining non-default names for field and property element tags.

One of the major uses of this is for custom configuration files as you stated; you can load the configuration from a persistent state by simply deserializing the file into an instance of the configuration object.

[Article: MSDN How To Serialize an Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szzyf24s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Ah, probably is just xml serialization. Thanks! Wasn't sure if I was looking for something more cryptic.

Comment: More specifically, it was the DataContractSerializer. I guess depending on specific needs, one or the other would be preferred.

Comment: The DataContractSerializer exists mainly for WCF, so it can do not only XML but also JSON. But, as you found, serialization is serialization when all you really need it to turn an object into a file on your own machine and back.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't part of the .Net bcl or Unity as far as I am aware.  Perhaps it's some other third party or open source component?  That being said, it wouldn't be too difficult to build something like this on your own using XmlSerialization.

Answer (score 0):

.net allows for multi layered configuration.

Every machine has the machine.config file. each application has the app.config file (which gets renamed to applicationname.exe.config upon building), but each dll can also have it's own config file. so, if I have the following binaries in my executable folder:

```
flexitris.exe
flexitrisHelpers.dll
thirdPartyContent.dll
```

each of them can have their own config file:

```
flexitris.exe.config
flexitrisHelpers.dll.config
thirdPartyContent.dll.config
```

and all of them will be read at runtime and accessible using the normal System.Configuration namespace.